# How to adjust scale ranges in altair?

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I'm having trouble getting all of the axes onto the same scale when using altair to make a group of plots like so:

```
class_list = ['c-CS-m','c-CS-s','c-SC-m','c-SC-s','t-CS-m','t-CS-s','t-SC-m','t-SC-s']
list_of_plots = []

for class_name in class_list:
    list_of_plots.append(alt.Chart(data[data['class'] == class_name]).mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('DYRK1A', bin = True, scale=alt.Scale()),
    y = 'count()').resolve_scale(
    y='independent'
))

list_of_plots[0] & list_of_plots[1] | list_of_plots[2] & list_of_plots[3] | list_of_plots[4] & list_of_plots[5] | list_of_plots[6] & list_of_plots[7]
```

I'd like to have the x axis run from 0.0 to 1.4 and the y axis run from 0 to 120 so that all eight plots I'm producing are on the same scale! I've tried to use domain, inside the currently empty `Scale()` call but it seems to result in the visualisations that have x axis data from say 0.0 to 0.3 being super squished up and I can't understand why?

For context, I'm trying to plot continuous values for protein expression levels. The 8 plots are for different classes of mice that have been exposed to different conditions. The data is available at this link if that helps: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Mice+Protein+Expression

Please let me know if I need to provide some more info in order for you to help me!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you're trying to create a wrapped facet chart. Rather than doing that manually with concatenation, it's better to use a [wrapped facet encoding](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/beckers_barley_wrapped_facet.html).

Second, when you specify `resolve_scale(y='independent')`, you're specifying that the y-scales should *not* match between subcharts. If instead you want all scales to be shared, you can use `resolve_scale(y='shared')`, or equivalently just leave that out, as it is the default.

To specify explicit axis domains, use `alt.Scale(domain=[min, max])`. Put together, it might look something like this:

```
alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('DYRK1A', bin = True, scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 1.4])),
    y = alt.Y('count()', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 120]),
    facet = alt.Facet('class:N', columns=4),
)
```